# Pidgin showing "Unable to connect" message with Gmail chat

Tags: gmail, pidgin, chat

I am unable to connect to gmail chat through pidgin (2.10.9) on Debian.

But Facebook chat is working fine.

Have tried this:

1. Google support https://support.google.com/a/answer/49147?hl=en
2. [a blog suggestion](http://mylinuxbook.com/how-to-get-pidgin-working-with-gtalk/)

Telnet shows

```
$ telnet gmail.com 5222 
Trying 74.125.236.86... 
Trying 74.125.236.85... 
Trying 2404:6800:4007:801::1015... 
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

Tried pidgin FAQ suggestion

at console

```
dig +short SRV _xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com
```

gives

```
5 0 5222 xmpp.l.google.com.
20 0 5222 alt4.xmpp.l.google.com. 
20 0 5222 alt2.xmpp.l.google.com. 
20 0 5222 alt1.xmpp.l.google.com.
20 0 5222 alt3.xmpp.l.google.com.
```

Comment: Check your netwrok. There seems to be some issue

Comment: I have internet access.Also, fb chat is working with pidgin. What else can I check, any suggestion?

Comment: your firewall seems to be blocking those ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabled [allow less secure apps option in Google account](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). This solved the problems with all the standard pidgin settings for the gtalk.

Comment: Not the greatest solution, since it explicitly makes your account less secure. Is there any way other than this?

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather old, but I still encountered this problem today. So, here's a solution. Use these settings in the advanced tab:

```
Connection security: "Use old-style SSL"
Connect port: 5223
Connect server: talk.google.com
```

Particularly setting the Connect server appears to be important.